# Problems using iosrtc plugin in hybrid Cordova iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova, webrtc, cordova-plugins

I'm creating a native iOS app, where I'm adding in Cordova to use the `CDVViewController` for one controller. This works as it should. I'm then adding [`cordova-plugin-iosrtc`](https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) to add WebRTC capabilities to that web view.

If I'm creating a complete Cordova app from scratch, I'm able to get it to work, but not while doing it as a part of the native app. Everything works, until I try to make a call, then I get this error:

```
ERROR: Method 'getUserMedia:' not defined in Plugin 'iosrtcPlugin'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you fix that?

Comment: @WorieN Yes. But I don't remember exactly how. Working with Cordova + iosrtc was the worst dev. experience of my life. Had tons of problems, and wouldn't recommend going down that path, if not totally nececarry.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I think I don't have choice.

Answer (score 3):

If your project uses swift version 4 or higher try to add attribute @objcMembers to the iosrtcPlugin, its allow to access to swift functions when its called by objc code

`@objcMembers
 class iosrtcPlugin : CDVPlugin`